# Web Assemblies WASM Newbie

Tags: c++, web, assemblies

I've just started reading up on Web Assemblies "the future of the web".
There are a few web pages telling me it'll do this, it'll do that etc.

I ok with C / C++ (that's my back ground years ago). I'm more than ok with JavaScript/Angular/React; WebWorkers etc.

If I want to start experimenting with this what do I need ?
What browsers ? Chromium ?. What compiler / assembler.
How do I "upload" it into a browser etc etc.

-- EDIT-- How do I get started ?

Comment: `There are a few web pages telling me it'll do this, it'll do that etc.` Can you add some references?

Comment: here's one I was looking at yesterday http://www.2ality.com/2015/06/web-assembly.html. My simple question really is. How do I get started ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is set of steps that I (someone with C, C++, OpenGL skills) would follow, to get started with WebAssembly:

1. See if you or your company is interested/impacted in any of use cases listed here: https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/UseCases.md. Personally for me CAD application in web are interesting use case.
2. Understand that WebAssembly binary format or text format is not yet fully defined. **a.** Hence NOT supported by any browser. **b.** There is no compiler support to generate WebAssembly.
3. While we wait, [what do we do](https://kripken.github.io/talks/wasm.html#/6)?

   ```
   C++  ⇒  Emscripten  ⇒  asm.js
   ```
4. For someone with C++ background, [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) is good starting point. It will convert your existing C++ code into [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/faq.html), which is subset of JavaScript that executes fast and you will have to use until browsers support WebAssembly, someday. See emscripten [tutorial here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html).
5. Study examples of C++ code base converted to asm.js and available online, like this one. https://www.unrealengine.com/html5/
6. Convert you own existing C++ program to asm.js and get it working in the browser.
7. Test new tools and report bugs to project maintainer.

Comment: Thank you, my interest is in music synthesis. What I was thinking was off loading a DSP / number crunching engine into Wasm . But one step at a time, gulp !